# Error while parsing date from json to object

Tags: java, json, parsing, exception, java.util.date

I have a json as

```
{"redemptionStartDate":1436950251941,"redemptionEndDate":1500108651941}
```

and I am trying to parse this json into an object which has date objects(java.util.Date) as

```
private Date redemptionStartDate;
private Date redemptionEndDate;
```

I am getting error as com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException while parsing into those Date objects. How can I resolve this issue?

Method to parse json

```
  public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    T obj = gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
    return obj;
  }
```

Comment: They seem to be `long` notation of `date`. You  will have to convert this (in millis) to date.

Comment: Yes they are long notations of date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class,

```
private Date redemptionStartDate;
private Date redemptionEndDate;
```

change this to

```
private long redemptionStartDate;
private long redemptionEndDate;
```

then u can use,

```
private Date redemptionStartDateVal;
private Date redemptionEndDateVal;
```

and in getters of these, set their values as :

```
redemptionStartDateVal = new Date(redemptionStartDate);
return redemptionStartDateVal;
```

See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)

Comment: Oops forgot the `new`. Typo error. Corrected now.@JordiCastilla Downvote was for that??

Comment: *it was, yes* , but also the comment so you can fix it `;)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JordiCastilla.

Comment: @RajatNigam Happy to help :)